# The start time should be start of a Local Time Zone day for DAY query

Tags: datetime, datetime-format, snapchat

I have some problem with correct formatting query for SnapChat API. 
I need to obtain some info for last day.
I read [official doc](https://developers.snapchat.com/api/docs/?shell#request-response-pattern) and made request with next parameters:

> start_time=2018-03-25T00:00:00.00+02:00
>      end_time=2018-03-26T00:00:00.00+02:00
>      granularity=DAY

Where +02::00 is my time zone. 
Instead of result, I got an error with a message

> "The start time should be start of a Local Time Zone day for DAY
>   query."

I can't figure out what is wrong with start_time parameter. Where is mistake?

Answer (score 1):

start_time timezone should match the timezone setup at the ad account level.
With moment.js, you could use something like:

```
moment.tz(start_time, adaccount.timezone).toISOString();
```

Answer (score 0):

try `-02:00`

I am guessing that you'd want to put `-09:00` for (Central Africa Timezone)

for me to convert back to UTC, I used the following:

`stats?granularity=DAY&start_time=2018-04-01T00:00:00.00-07:00&end_time=2018-04-05T00:00:00.00-07:00`

- granularity = DAY
- start_time = 2018-04-01T00:00:00.00-07:00
- end_time = 2018-04-05T00:00:00.00-07:00